# Issues integrating Google authenticator with laravel 5.6.HOW to integrate Google authentication 2 step process

Tags: laravel, google-authentication, google-authenticator

I had la-ravel 5.4 previously I followed few links but of to no avail.
I used a "Google" package too but it also causes some errors regularly following the process.
Not able to find the right link to follow to integrate Google authentication with la-ravel 5.6

Comment: i tried "pragmarx/google2fa" and followed the steps still the issue persist. does anyone has the latest way to integrate google authenticator with laravel 5.4 and higher versions.

Comment: ive used `pragmarx/google2fa` without any issues. If you could post what errors you are getting that will help finding a solution easier

Comment: got it done now, just packages isseuess